# Denmark, everyone over 30 dies from a disease

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book of which the story takes place in Denmark.

The story:
Everyone over 30 dies from some disease, probably a virus.
Two boys take a ferry from one Danish island to another Danish island, after which they almost get conscripted into the army.
These two boys also try to avoid the main roads, because of checkpoints.
Another detail I remember, is that in the beginning of the book, they talk about science or bio-engineering, in which they describe that in the near future, it would be possible to create a kind of disease that would only target a specific kind of mouse (e.g. only the ones with a black tail or something like it).

Publishing information:
The book has been translated into Dutch, but the original was probably Danish.
It was published in the '00s, '90s or before, as that is when I read it.

Comment: "Everyone over 30 dies" reminded me of TOS "Miri" episode, which led me to TVTropes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OnlyFatalToAdults (insert obligatory TVTropes black hole warning) but I don't see an exact match there.

Comment: @shoover I read everything on that page, but unfortunately nothing I recognize as this story! I guess it's a quite unknown children's book.